# transformar sql com subquery em query no entity

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Estou precisando e estou com dificuldades de pegar esse sql com subquery e fazer a mesma coisa em c# entity.

```
SELECT  Id,Nome,
      (SELECT Count(Id) FROM Pedidos
      WHERE Pedidos.ColaboradorId = Colaborador.Id) AS NumeroPedidos
  FROM Colaborador
  ORDER BY Nome DESC;
```

Preciso transformar esse SQL acima.

```
var retornoColaborador = db.Colaboradores.Where(a => a.Id == db.Pedidos.Where(b => b.ColaboradorId == a.Id).Count());
```

Tentei fazer algo parecido com isso mas não deu certo.

Comment: Eu uso o *LINQPad* para ajudar a construir essas expressões, pode te ajudar: http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: O que esse linqpad faz?

Comment: é uma ferramenta que te ajuda a testar código, você pode conectar no banco de dados e ir montando as expressões ou linq e ele vai mostrando a query sql correspondente

Comment: Top demais. valeu pela dica

Comment: se dentro de `Colaborador` você tiver `Pedidos` bastaria selecionar Colaboradores, e a quantidade de pedidos seria `colaborador.Pedidos.Count`

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa de uma *subquery* para resolver esse problema, um `LEFT JOIN` combinado com um `SUM()` pode te ajudar, veja só:

```
SELECT
    Colaborador.Id,
    Colaborador.Nome,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Pedidos.Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS NumeroPedidos
FROM
    Colaborador
LEFT JOIN
    Pedidos ON ( Pedidos.ColaboradorId = Colaborador.Id )
GROUP BY
    Colaborador.Id,
    Colaborador.Nome
ORDER BY
    Colaborador.Nome DESC;
```

Comment: Eu preciso transformar a query que eu fiz em entity para c#

Comment: Mas você me deu uma ideia aqui, posso usar sql puro para ele

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma, ao dar `include`, já é feita a `sub query`

```
var retornoColaborador = db.Colaboradores.Include(p=> p.Pedidos).Select(p => new
    {
        p.ColaboradorId,
        p.Nome,
        p.Pedidos.Count
    });
```

Comment: Esse p.Pedidos não funciona, não acha

Comment: Tem como adicionar na pergunta as duas classes sua?, Achei que tinha uma propriedade navegativa rsrs